# ValueError when resampling Pandas' dataframe with BusinessHour frequency

Tags: dataframe, python-3.6, pandas

I want to resample my dataframe so that the resolution changes from order minutes to hours. This resampling should occur on the business hours only. However, when using the built in object from Pandas I encounter a ValueError. This is strange because is does work when the Hour offset object is used. See my steps below.

```py
>>> import yfinance as yf

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import Hour, BusinessHour


# Example data with 5 minute interval
>>> mydata = yf.Ticker('ABN.AS').history(interval='5m', period='1mo', start='2020-06-01')
```

Resampling `mydata` with Pandas's Hour offset object, the process works as expected.

```py
>>> mydatahour = mydata.resample(Hour()).mean()
                               Open      High       Low     Close         Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Datetime
2020-06-01 09:00:00+02:00  7.610833  7.648333  7.588333  7.625000  235704.416667        0.0           0.0
2020-06-01 10:00:00+02:00  7.580000  7.602500  7.551667  7.580000  139965.166667        0.0           0.0
2020-06-01 11:00:00+02:00  7.621667  7.634167  7.608333  7.620833   88396.833333        0.0           0.0
2020-06-01 12:00:00+02:00  7.581667  7.595000  7.570000  7.581667   49044.166667        0.0           0.0
2020-06-01 13:00:00+02:00  7.622500  7.628333  7.615833  7.621667   44186.666667        0.0           0.0
...                             ...       ...       ...       ...            ...        ...           ...
2020-07-09 09:00:00+02:00  8.000000  8.015000  7.973333  7.989167   59975.333333        0.0           0.0
2020-07-09 10:00:00+02:00  7.970000  7.976667  7.952500  7.965000   26809.250000        0.0           0.0
2020-07-09 11:00:00+02:00  7.920000  7.927500  7.909167  7.915833   18170.166667        0.0           0.0
2020-07-09 12:00:00+02:00  7.892500  7.900000  7.885000  7.891667   22465.583333        0.0           0.0
2020-07-09 13:00:00+02:00  7.887692  7.893846  7.880769  7.889231   18324.153846        0.0           0.0
```

Resampling `mydata` with Pandas' BusinessHour object the following exception is thrown:

```py
>>> mydatahour = mydata.resample(BusinessHour()).mean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bramb\Documents\codes\fanalysis\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 937, in g
    return self._downsample(_method)
  File "C:\Users\bramb\Documents\codes\fanalysis\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1020, in _downsample
    self._set_binner()
  File "C:\Users\bramb\Documents\codes\fanalysis\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 178, in _set_binner
    self.binner, self.grouper = self._get_binner()
  File "C:\Users\bramb\Documents\codes\fanalysis\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 186, in _get_binner
    binner, bins, binlabels = self._get_binner_for_time()
  File "C:\Users\bramb\Documents\codes\fanalysis\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1009, in _get_binner_for_time
    return self.groupby._get_time_bins(self.ax)
  File "C:\Users\bramb\Documents\codes\fanalysis\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1449, in _get_time_bins
    ax_values, bin_edges, self.closed, hasnans=ax.hasnans
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 673, in pandas._libs.lib.generate_bins_dt64
ValueError: Values falls after last bin
```

Using Pandas's groupby on `mydata` will give me the same error as above when using the Grouper object with the businesshour frequency ('BH').

```py
>>> mydatahour2 = mydata.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='BH')).mean()
```

Why do I get this exception, and how can I come up with a workaround? I've tried to subset pandas's Hour offset object but this is readonly so I cannot adapt it this way.